# handling Json CallBack API in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C programming. I have a problem with Objective C & json response. I am trying to get word definition from Google dictionary API. I am getting Json response. But the problem with it is i am getting callback respose. which can not be easily parse by json.
The API to which i am calling is

```
http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dict_api.callbacks.id100&q=test&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=prCde&client=te
```

and I am getting response as

```
dict_api.callbacks.id100({"query":"test","sourceLanguage":"en","targetLanguage":"en","primaries":[{"type":"headword","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"test","language":"en","labels":[{"text":"Noun","title":"Part-of-speech"}]},{"type":"phonetic","text":"/test/","language":"und"},{"type":"sound","text":"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/test.mp3","language":"und"}],"entries":[{"type":"related","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"tests","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"plural"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A procedure intended to establish the quality, performance, or reliability of something, esp. before it is taken into widespread use","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"no sparking was visible during the \x3cem\x3etests\x3c/em\x3e","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A short written or spoken examination of a person\x27s proficiency or knowledge","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a spelling \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"An event or situation that reveals the strength or quality of someone or something by putting them under strain","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"this is the first serious \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e of the peace agreement","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"An examination of part of the body or a body fluid for medical purposes, esp. by means of a chemical or mechanical procedure rather than simple inspection","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e for HIV","language":"en"}]},{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"eye \x3cem\x3etests\x3c/em\x3e","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A procedure employed to identify a substance or to reveal the presence or absence of a constituent within a substance","language":"en"}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"The result of a medical examination or analytical procedure","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a positive \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e for protein","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A means of establishing whether an action, item, or situation is an instance of a specified quality, esp. one held to be undesirable","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a statutory \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e of obscenity","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A movable hearth in a reverberating furnace, used for separating gold or silver from lead","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"headword","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"test","language":"en","labels":[{"text":"Verb","title":"Part-of-speech"}]},{"type":"phonetic","text":"/test/","language":"und"},{"type":"sound","text":"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/test.mp3","language":"und"}],"entries":[{"type":"related","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"tests","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"3rd person singular present"}]},{"type":"text","text":"tested","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"past participle"}]},{"type":"text","text":"testing","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"present participle"}]},{"type":"text","text":"tested","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"past tense"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Take measures to check the quality, performance, or reliability of (something), esp. before putting it into widespread use or practice","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"this range has not been \x3cem\x3etested\x3c/em\x3e on animals","language":"en"}]},{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"the \x3cem\x3etesting\x3c/em\x3e and developing of prototypes","language":"en"}]},{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a useful way to \x3cb\x3e\x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e out\x3c/b\x3e ideas before implementation","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Reveal the strengths or capabilities of (someone or something) by putting them under strain","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"such behavior would severely \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e any marriage","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Give (someone) a short written or oral examination of their proficiency or knowledge","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"all children are \x3cem\x3etested\x3c/em\x3e at eleven","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Judge or measure (someone\x27s proficiency or knowledge) by means of such an examination","language":"en"}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Carry out a medical \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e on (a person, a part of the body, or a body fluid)","language":"en"}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Produce a specified result in a medical \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e, esp. a drug \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e or AIDS \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"he \x3cb\x3e\x3cem\x3etested\x3c/em\x3e positive\x3c/b\x3e for steroids during the race","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Examine (a substance) by means of a reagent","language":"en"}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Touch or taste (something) to check that it is acceptable before proceeding further","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"she \x3cem\x3etested\x3c/em\x3e the water with the tip of her elbow","language":"en"}]}]}]},{"type":"headword","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"test","language":"en","labels":[{"text":"Noun","title":"Part-of-speech"}]},{"type":"sound","text":"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/test.mp3","language":"und"}],"entries":[{"type":"related","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"tests","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"plural"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"The shell or integument of some invertebrates and protozoans, esp. the chalky shell of a foraminiferan or the tough outer layer of a tunicate","language":"en"}]}]}]},200,null)
```

I am trying to save this response into NSArray as follows:

```
SBJSON *jsonParser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSArray *responseArray = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseString];
```

Even i tried this code with NSdictionary.

```
SBJSON *jsonParser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *responseDict = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseString];
```

But I am getting null dictionary. Where I am going wrong? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

SBJSON isn't able to parse the method call, you should change the API call in a way to return only JSON data and not the complete callback method call.

Try remove the callback parameter of url to return only JSON data like below, which is valid and parsable:

```
 {"query":"test","sourceLanguage":"en","targetLanguage":"en","primaries":[{"type":"headword","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"test","language":"en","labels":[{"text":"Noun","title":"Part-of-speech"}]},{"type":"phonetic","text":"/test/","language":"und"},{"type":"sound","text":"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/test.mp3","language":"und"}],"entries":[{"type":"related","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"tests","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"plural"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A procedure intended to establish the quality, performance, or reliability of something, esp. before it is taken into widespread use","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"no sparking was visible during the \x3cem\x3etests\x3c/em\x3e","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A short written or spoken examination of a person\x27s proficiency or knowledge","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a spelling \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"An event or situation that reveals the strength or quality of someone or something by putting them under strain","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"this is the first serious \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e of the peace agreement","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"An examination of part of the body or a body fluid for medical purposes, esp. by means of a chemical or mechanical procedure rather than simple inspection","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e for HIV","language":"en"}]},{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"eye \x3cem\x3etests\x3c/em\x3e","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A procedure employed to identify a substance or to reveal the presence or absence of a constituent within a substance","language":"en"}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"The result of a medical examination or analytical procedure","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a positive \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e for protein","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A means of establishing whether an action, item, or situation is an instance of a specified quality, esp. one held to be undesirable","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a statutory \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e of obscenity","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"A movable hearth in a reverberating furnace, used for separating gold or silver from lead","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"headword","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"test","language":"en","labels":[{"text":"Verb","title":"Part-of-speech"}]},{"type":"phonetic","text":"/test/","language":"und"},{"type":"sound","text":"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/test.mp3","language":"und"}],"entries":[{"type":"related","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"tests","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"3rd person singular present"}]},{"type":"text","text":"tested","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"past participle"}]},{"type":"text","text":"testing","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"present participle"}]},{"type":"text","text":"tested","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"past tense"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Take measures to check the quality, performance, or reliability of (something), esp. before putting it into widespread use or practice","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"this range has not been \x3cem\x3etested\x3c/em\x3e on animals","language":"en"}]},{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"the \x3cem\x3etesting\x3c/em\x3e and developing of prototypes","language":"en"}]},{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"a useful way to \x3cb\x3e\x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e out\x3c/b\x3e ideas before implementation","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Reveal the strengths or capabilities of (someone or something) by putting them under strain","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"such behavior would severely \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e any marriage","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Give (someone) a short written or oral examination of their proficiency or knowledge","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"all children are \x3cem\x3etested\x3c/em\x3e at eleven","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Judge or measure (someone\x27s proficiency or knowledge) by means of such an examination","language":"en"}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Carry out a medical \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e on (a person, a part of the body, or a body fluid)","language":"en"}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Produce a specified result in a medical \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e, esp. a drug \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e or AIDS \x3cem\x3etest\x3c/em\x3e","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"he \x3cb\x3e\x3cem\x3etested\x3c/em\x3e positive\x3c/b\x3e for steroids during the race","language":"en"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Examine (a substance) by means of a reagent","language":"en"}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"Touch or taste (something) to check that it is acceptable before proceeding further","language":"en"}],"entries":[{"type":"example","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"she \x3cem\x3etested\x3c/em\x3e the water with the tip of her elbow","language":"en"}]}]}]},{"type":"headword","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"test","language":"en","labels":[{"text":"Noun","title":"Part-of-speech"}]},{"type":"sound","text":"http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/test.mp3","language":"und"}],"entries":[{"type":"related","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"tests","language":"und","labels":[{"text":"plural"}]}]},{"type":"meaning","terms":[{"type":"text","text":"The shell or integument of some invertebrates and protozoans, esp. the chalky shell of a foraminiferan or the tough outer layer of a tunicate","language":"en"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: I tried to remove callback parameter but its giving me an error. It never processes my request without callback parameter. Is there any other way by which I can do this?

Comment: when I try to avoid callback parameter it gives me null response.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format is not proper. check it with -  http://json.parser.online.fr/

then try this :

```
    NSString *strResponse = [request responseString];
    SBJSON *objJSONParser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dictData = [objJSONParser objectWithString:strResponse error:nil];

     NSDictionary *dictResult = [dictData objectForKey: @"response"];
     NSString *strQuery=[dictResult objectForKey:@"query"];.......... with your Key..
```

and get array like this

```
     NSArray *arrPrimaries=(NSArray *)[dictData objectForKey:@"primaries"];
```

Comment: Yess.... Samir. You are right. My jsonp reponse is not valid. It contains some string which can not be parsed by json parser. But it will be very difficult to replace each and every. What can i do.

Answer (score 0):

There is one ad-hoc solution for this problem. Try to strip `dict_api.callbacks.id100(` from the beginning of the response, and `,200,null)` from the end. Something like:

```
responseString = [responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@"dict_api.callbacks.id100("][1];
responseString = [responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@",200,null)"][0];

SBJSON *objJSONParser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dictData = [objJSONParser objectWithString:strResponse error:nil];
// ... so on
```

Be aware it is an ad-hoc solution and it may not work for any other responses. Follow the advice of @ararog: find API to get JSON-only response.

Comment: Thanx Vova. But I already did this and now I am able to get response in json format. But still sometimes it gives me null NSDictionary and sometimes it works fine. Is this because it is an ad-hoc solution? I can't avoid callback parameter. What should i do?

Comment: when I try to avoid callback parameter it gives me null response.

Comment: @user2063425, yes, probably, because the response may vary from time-to-time so this workaround doens't work.

Comment: I think, I got the exact problem. As Samir said my json response is not a valid one. It contains some regular expression type values like "\x3cem\x3e". I don't know why it is used for? But it is there and won't allow json parser to parse json string. You can even check it in response given above.